# Breaking a lengthy row into multiple rows using Xpath expression in Altova Stylevision's Autocalc functionality

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0, altova

I have a XML row  which has a lengthy sentence for instance:

```
    <ROW>4.)Whatever universe a professor believes in must at any rate be a universe that lends itself to lengthy discourse. A universe definable in two sentences is something for which the professorial intellect has no use. No faith in anything of that cheap kind!
```

I need to break the sentence into smaller sentences and display them in multiple lines in Altova Stylevision.

Iam using Autocalc to display the contents in row dynamically. Is there any Xpath expression which I can use to split the row into multiple rows based on the number of words or number of characters  in each line.So that I can display the row as:

```
    Whatever universe a professor believes in must at any rate
    be a universe that lends itself to lengthy discourse.
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to break your string input into multiple pieces (word/String length). I have created a sample for you to make it easy. Please go through and check if it can help you:

**input xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROW>4.)Whatever universe a professor believes in must at any rate be a universe that lends itself to lengthy discourse. A universe definable in two sentences is something for which the professorial intellect has no use. No faith in anything of that cheap kind!11</ROW>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="ROW">
    <output>
    <xsl:variable name="Length" select="string-length(.)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Words" select="count(tokenize(.,'\s'))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ByLength" select="50"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ByWord" select="5"/>
    <!-- To get ouput by words -->
      <xsl:if test="$ByWord">
        <xsl:variable name="Result">
            <xsl:call-template name="GetBreakingWords">
              <xsl:with-param name="Value" select="."/>
              <xsl:with-param name="ByWord" select="$ByWord"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="Words" select="$Words"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <p>By word example</p>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Result/row">
          <xsl:sort select="@id" data-type="number"/>
          <!--<row><xsl:value-of select="."/></row>-->
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:if>
      <!-- To get ouput by string length -->
      <xsl:if test="$ByLength">
        <xsl:variable name="Result">
          <xsl:call-template name="GetBreakingStrings">
            <xsl:with-param name="Value" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="ByLength" select="$ByLength"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="Length" select="$Length"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <p>By String example</p>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Result/row">
          <xsl:sort select="@id" data-type="number"/>
          <!--<row><xsl:value-of select="."/></row>-->
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:if>

    </output>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="GetBreakingWords">
    <xsl:param name="ByWord"/>
    <xsl:param name="Value"/>
    <xsl:param name="Words"/>
    <xsl:param name="counter" select="1"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="($Words gt $ByWord)">
      <xsl:variable name="CurrentRow" select="normalize-space(string-join(for $x in tokenize($Value, '\s')[position() ge 1 and position() le $ByWord] return $x, ' '))"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="GetBreakingWords">
        <xsl:with-param name="ByWord" select="$ByWord"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="Words" select="count(tokenize(substring-after($Value, $CurrentRow),'\s'))"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="Value" select="substring-after($Value, $CurrentRow)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="sum($counter + 1)"></xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
        <row id="{$counter}"><xsl:value-of select="$CurrentRow"/></row>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="not($Words gt $ByWord) and $Value">
        <row id="{$counter}"><xsl:value-of select="$Value"/></row>
      </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="GetBreakingStrings">
    <xsl:param name="ByLength"/>
    <xsl:param name="Value"/>
    <xsl:param name="Length"/>
    <xsl:param name="counter" select="1"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="($Length gt $ByLength)">
        <xsl:variable name="CurrentRow" select="normalize-space(string-join(substring($Value,0,$ByLength),' '))"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="GetBreakingStrings">
          <xsl:with-param name="ByLength" select="$ByLength"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="Length" select="string-length(substring-after($Value, $CurrentRow))"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="Value" select="substring-after($Value, $CurrentRow)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="sum($counter + 1)"></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <row id="{$counter}"><xsl:value-of select="$CurrentRow"/></row>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="not($Length gt $ByLength) and $Value">
        <row id="{$counter}"><xsl:value-of select="$Value"/></row>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <p>By word example</p>
   <row id="1">4.)Whatever universe a professor believes</row>
   <row id="2">in must at any</row>
   <row id="3">rate be a universe</row>
   <row id="4">that lends itself to</row>
   <row id="5">lengthy discourse. A universe</row>
   <row id="6">definable in two sentences</row>
   <row id="7">is something for which</row>
   <row id="8">the professorial intellect has</row>
   <row id="9">no use. No faith</row>
   <row id="10">in anything of that</row>
   <row id="11"> cheap kind!11</row>
   <p>By String example</p>
   <row id="1">4.)Whatever universe a professor believes in must</row>
   <row id="2">at any rate be a universe that lends itself to l</row>
   <row id="3">engthy discourse. A universe definable in two sen</row>
   <row id="4">tences is something for which the professorial in</row>
   <row id="5">tellect has no use. No faith in anything of that</row>
   <row id="6"> cheap kind!11</row>
</output>
```